# Does an instance of class containing no objects create a heap entry

Tags: c#, heap-memory, stack-memory

If a new instance of a class contains no objects does it create a heap entry (with nothing in it) or just a stack entry with no reference/pointer to a position on the heap? Does the new instance of an empty class use any heap memory? For example:

```
class MyClass
{
}
class Program
{
     Static void Main(string [] args)
     {
            MyClass mc = new MyClass();
     }
}
```

Comment: No Fields doesn't mean no data. Especially in .Net. There will be meta-information about the class, what type it is, sizes, reference counts, etc. I would guess it still puts data on the heap.

Comment: Yeah that sounds right. Classes are reference types so require the heap for storage. Any memory requirement at all must be allocated on the heap even if it's small. Frustratingly I can't find out this information. Is anyone certain on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that creates an object on the heap. There will be a reference to it on the stack (unless it is optimized away because the reference is not used).

The object instance will contain some header/metadata even if the class has zero non-static fields.

Also, the simple expression statement

```
{
    new object();
}
```

creates an object on the heap, even if you don't use the reference to it.

Comment: Ah ok that's interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The object cannot be allocated on the stack because the object's lifetime may continue beyond the end of the function which instantiates it. The object instance will be created on the heap.